# Team Explorer missing in Visual studio 2017

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio Code 2017 and I am not able to locate team explorer and I need it to use git in VS it is supposed to be present in "view" but it is not.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KKSq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Team Explorer is part of Visual Studio 2017. Visual Studio Code is a different program. Your image is from Visual Studio Code (not visual studio).